# Unexpected (case-insensitive) string sorting in Elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, case-insensitive

I have a list of console platforms that I'm sorting in Elasticsearch.

Here is the mapping for the "name" field:

```
{
    "name": {
        "type": "multi_field",
        "fields": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "analyzed"
            },
            "sort_name": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
    "sort": [
        {
          "name.sort_name": { "order": "asc" }
        }
    ],
    "fields": ["name"]
}
```

I get these results:

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 3,
        "successful": 3,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 17,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "platforms",
                "_type": "platform",
                "_id": "1393602489",
                "_score": null,
                "fields": {
                    "name": "GameCube"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "GameCube"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "platforms",
                "_type": "platform",
                "_id": "1393602490",
                "_score": null,
                "fields": {
                    "name": "Gameboy Advance"
                },
                "sort": [
                    "Gameboy Advance"
                ]
            },


    {
            "_index": "platforms",
            "_type": "platform",
            "_id": "1393602498",
            "_score": null,
            "fields": {
                "name": "Nintendo 3DS"
            },
            "sort": [
                "Nintendo 3DS"
            ]
        },

        ...remove for brevity ...

        {
            "_index": "platforms",
            "_type": "platform",
            "_id": "1393602493",
            "_score": null,
            "fields": {
                "name": "Xbox 360"
            },
            "sort": [
                "Xbox 360"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_index": "platforms",
            "_type": "platform",
            "_id": "1393602502",
            "_score": null,
            "fields": {
                "name": "Xbox One"
            },
            "sort": [
                "Xbox One"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_index": "platforms",
            "_type": "platform",
            "_id": "1393602497",
            "_score": null,
            "fields": {
                "name": "iPhone/iPod"
            },
            "sort": [
                "iPhone/iPod"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Everything is sorted as expected except the `iPhone/iPod` result is at the end (instead of after GameBoy Advance) - why does the `/` in the name have an effect on the sorting?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Okay so I discovered the reason wasn't anything to do with the `/`. ES will sort by capital letters then lower case letters.

I added a custom analyzer to the `settings` of the index creation:

```
{
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "sortable": {
                "tokenizer": "keyword",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the field mapping I added `'analyzer': 'sortable'` to the `sort_name` multi field.

Comment: Is this really the simplest way you can achieve case insensitive sorting?

Comment: This works but is slow - results are taking 3 seconds to determine when sorting ascending, 15 seconds when sorting descending!

Comment: I have a doubt here, If we havent defined any analyzer standard analyzer will be the default one but standard analyzer is shipped with lower case filter So then why its not sorted as we expected when using standard analyzer

Answer (score 2):

Use Normalizer with keyword to handle the sort

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-normalizers.html#analysis-normalizers

```
PUT index_name
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": ["quote"],
          "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search query may be modified like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
    "sort": [
        {
          "name.sort_name": { "order": "asc" }
        }
    ],
    "fields": "name.keyword"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-normalizers.html (ElasticSearch 7.16) ...

> Elasticsearch ships with a lowercase built-in normalizer.

So you can define an additional field (in the example below named "lowersortable"):

```
PUT /myindex/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "myproperty": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "lowersortable": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "normalizer": "lowercase"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... and use this field `myproperty.lowersortable` for sorting in the search query.

Comment: I have a doubt here, If we havent defined any analyzer standard analyzer will be the default one but standard analyzer is shipped with lower case filter So then why its not sorted as we expected when using standard analyzer