# Elasticsearch in Django - sort alphabetically

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a following doc:

```
@brand.doc_type
class BrandDocument(DocType):

    class Meta:
        model = Brand

    id = IntegerField()
    name = StringField(
        fields={
            'raw': {
                'type': 'keyword',
                'fielddata': True,
            }
        },
    )
    lookup_name = StringField(
        fields={
            'raw': {
                'type': 'string',
            }
        },
    )
```

and I try to make a lookup using this:

```
BrandDocument.search().sort({
    'name.keyword': order,
})
```

The problem is that I'm getting results sorted in a case sensitive way, which means that instead of `'a', 'A', 'ab', 'AB'` I get `'A', 'AB', 'a', 'ab'`. How can this be fixed?

**EDIT** After some additional search I've come up with something like this:

```
lowercase_normalizer = normalizer(
    'lowercase_normalizer',
    filter=['lowercase']
)
lowercase_analyzer = analyzer(
    'lowercase_analyzer',
    tokenizer="keyword",
    filter=['lowercase'],
)


@brand.doc_type
class BrandDocument(DocType):

    class Meta:
        model = Brand

    id = IntegerField()
    name = StringField(
        analyzer=lowercase_analyzer,
        fields={
            'raw': Keyword(normalizer=lowercase_normalizer, fielddata=True),
        },
    )
```

The issue persists, however, and I can't find in the docs how this normalizer should be used.

Comment: Take a look at this answer; https://stackoverflow.com/a/22100849/1199464

Comment: You are storing the values as is, so they will be sorted case sensitive. If you want a different sort order, you need to store the values differently (case insensitive, and for languages with diacritica, you might want to consider a filter like ICU to resolve accents and such so that ü, ue, ú are sorted accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a custom analyzer with lowercase filter and apply it to the field while indexing.

So you have to update the following in the index **settings**:

```
{
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_sort": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Add a field (based on which you need to sort) in mapping with the ***custom_sort*** analyzer as below:

```
{
    "properties":{
        "sortField":{
            "type":"text",
            "analyzer":"custom_sort"
        }
    }
}
```

If the field already exists in mapping then you can add a sub fields to the existing field with the analyzer as below.

Assuming the field ***name*** having type as ***keyword*** already exists, update it as:

```
{
    "properties":{
        "name":{
            "type": "keyword",
            "fields":{
                "sortval":{
                    "type":"text",
                    "analyzer":"custom_sort"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once done you need to reindex your data so that lowercase values are indexed. Then you can use the field to sort as:

Case 1 (new field):

```
"sort": [
    {
      "sortField": "desc"
    }
  ]
```

Case 2 (sub field):

```
"sort": [
    {
      "name.sortval": "desc"
    }
  ]
```