# elastic search version 6-7 , analyzer used for sort not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating the following `my_cars` index

```
PUT my_cars
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "sortable": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": "sortable"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When i check the mapping , it seems fine :-

```
{
  "my_cars" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : "sortable"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But now when i run the query for search and sort

```
GET my_cars/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "name.keyword": {
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

The capital/uppercase results show up first , hence making me think the analyzer is not working fine. the result i get is as follows :-

```
{
  "took" : 163,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_cars",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "f1RLUnoBZEZpPd-TeK9L",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Apples",
          "price" : 250
        },
        "sort" : [
          "Apples"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_cars",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "H7JLUnoBh60DJePfnpGB",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Brocoli",
          "price" : 250
        },
        "sort" : [
          "Brocoli"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_cars",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "gFRLUnoBZEZpPd-Tyq9A",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "azus",
          "price" : 110
        },
        "sort" : [
          "azus"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_cars",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "gVRMUnoBZEZpPd-TAq-A",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "botpzus",
          "price" : 80
        },
        "sort" : [
          "botpzus"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see the lowercase names come in last, how do i fix this ? I have build my analyzer based on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099906/unexpected-case-insensitive-string-sorting-in-elasticsearch) question. But unlike the answer in that question , i am unable to add the analyzer field directly inside the `keyword` mapping. How do i fix my alphabetical search irrespective of casing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to [use a `normalizer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-normalizers.html) on the `name.keyword`:

```
PUT my_cars
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "sortable": {
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "sortable"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks , works fine now , just curious , why can't ```"analyzer": "sortable"``` be applied to `keyword` , just the way `"normalizer": "sortable"` is applied ?